# How to convert Amount from string to float in sql array?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, google-visualization

I have problem connected with function returning array from sql query. The problem is that I want to return category as string and amount as float. I think the best solution is to set in while loop to write that i want category as string and amount as float. But I don't know which function can I use to make this ?

I was thinking to write something like this in while loop

```
while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
           {
                $data[] = [(string)$row['Category'],(float)$row['Amount']];
           }
```

But there is no result, that I expected.

```
public static function getPieChartIncomes()
{   
    if (empty(Income::$this->errors)) {

        $sql = "SELECT income_category_assigned_to_user_id as Category, SUM(amount) as Amount FROM incomes WHERE user_id = :userId  GROUP BY income_category_assigned_to_user_id ORDER BY SUM(amount)  DESC ";

        $db = static::getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':userId', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
           $data=array();
           while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
           {
                $data[] = $row;
           }
        return $data;
    }

    return false;
}


public static function convertDataToChartForm($data)
{
$newData = array();
$firstLine = true;

foreach ($data as $dataRow)
{
    if ($firstLine)
    {
        $newData[] = array_keys($dataRow);
        $firstLine = false;
    }

    $newData[] = array_values($dataRow);
}

return $newData;
}
```

Finally I wanted to achieve Array for google charts like this one:

```
$chartIncomesArray = Income::convertDataToChartForm($incomesArray);
json_encode($chartIncomesArray) =
['Category']['Amount']
['wynagrodzenie'][12.00]
['odsetki'][50.00]
etc.
```

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: It looks like your problem is not in the codes. It looks like the data from the database is not float.

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual values you have stored in your database? And what exactly you are getting in your result right now, when you don't "convert" it? (And what sense is the part about converting the category even supposed to make? Why should `wynagrodzenie` need converting into a string value - what _else_ could it possibly be, if not a string value already?)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, deleting convertDataToChartForm($data) and changing getPieChartIncomes function to this:

```
public static function getPieChartIncomes()
    {   
        if (empty(Income::$this->errors)) {

            $sql = "SELECT income_category_assigned_to_user_id as Category, SUM(amount) as Amount FROM incomes WHERE user_id = :userId  GROUP BY income_category_assigned_to_user_id ORDER BY SUM(amount)  DESC ";

            $db = static::getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':userId', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $i = 1;
            $stmt->execute();
            $tablica = array();
            
               while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
               {
                $firstLine = true;
                if ($firstLine)
                {
                    $tablica[0] = array_keys($row);
                    $firstLine = false;
                }
                   $category = $row['Category'];
                   $amount = $row['Amount'];
                   $tablica[$i]=array(strval($category),floatval($amount));
                   $i++;
               }
            return $tablica;
        }
```

Thanks to while loop like now i can get table, where array keys are strings and another rows are : category as string and amount as int like this

```
['Category']['Amount']
['wynagrodzenie'][12.00]
['odsetki'][50.00]
```